# C++: Memory allocators

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've heard about people using custom memory allocators for their project, particulary in C++.

- What is a custom memory allocator, compared to malloc?
- Isn't malloc the lowest level you can go already?

Comment: @muntoo: that doesn't mention allocators at all.

Comment: @jalf I'm still learning how to read.

Answer (score 20):

A memory allocator isn't *lower level* than `malloc`. (The default allocator typically calls `malloc` directly or indirectly)

An allocator just allows you to specify different allocation strategies. For example, you might use an allocator which calls `malloc` once to retrieve a large pool of memory, and then for subsequent allocation requests, it just returns a small chunk of this pool.

Or you may use it as a hook to allow you to perform some additional task every time memory is allocated or freed.

As to your second question, `malloc` is the lowest you can go without losing portability. `malloc` is typically implemented using some OS-specific memory allocation function, so that would be lower level still. But that's unrelated to your main question, since C++ allocators are a higher-level abstraction.

Comment: +1- there are many allocation strategies, malloc is just one that's intended to be as generically performant as possible.

Answer (score 17):

There's an extensive description of custom allocators, along with their empirical evaluation, in the following paper (that I co-wrote). Before you decide to use custom allocators in *your* C++ project, you should give this paper a read. The executive overview is *a good general-purpose allocator is better (faster and more space-efficient) than all styles of custom allocators except regions, but these have serious problems*.

**Reconsidering Custom Memory Allocation** ([ACM link](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=582421), [direct PDF link](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/berger-oopsla2002.pdf), [Powerpoint talk slides](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/talks/OOPSLA-2002.ppt)), OOPSLA 2002.

> Programmers hoping to achieve
>   performance improvements often use
>   custom memory allocators. This
>   in-depth study examines eight
>   applications that use custom
>   allocators. Surprisingly, for six of
>   these applications, a state-of-the-art
>   general-purpose allocator (the Lea
>   allocator) performs as well as or
>   better than the custom allocators. The
>   two exceptions use regions, which
>   deliver higher performance
>   (improvements of up to 44%). Regions
>   also reduce programmer burden and
>   eliminate a source of memory leaks.
>   However, we show that the inability of
>   programmers to free individual objects
>   within regions can lead to a
>   substantial increase in memory
>   consumption. Worse, this limitation
>   precludes the use of regions for
>   common programming idioms, reducing
>   their usefulness.We present a
>   generalization of general-purpose and
>   region-based allocators that we call
>   reaps. Reaps are a combination of
>   regions and heaps, providing a full
>   range of region semantics with the
>   addition of individual object
>   deletion. We show that our
>   implementation of reaps provides high
>   performance, outperforming other
>   allocators with region-like semantics.
>   We then use a case study to
>   demonstrate the space advantages and
>   software engineering benefits of reaps
>   in practice. Our results indicate that
>   programmers needing fast regions
>   should use reaps, and that most
>   programmers considering custom
>   allocators should instead use the Lea
>   allocator.

Answer (score 5):

A custom memory allocator is a replacement for `malloc` (actually, usually a replacement for `operator new`) that retrieves blocks of bytes in some fashion other than the default.  `malloc` is not the lowest level you can go, because `malloc` itself is implemented in terms of even simpler primitives from the OS that allocate blocks of memory for partitioning.

Common use cases for making custom allocators are optimizing for allocations of small objects (the default allocator is usually really bad at this), allocating in a way that guarantees good locality (by allocating objects near one another), allocating with logging/tracking (to diagnose leaks), allocating from a garbage-collected resource pool, etc.  There are a lot of different options available, and many programs can squeeze out a bit more performance using these custom allocators.

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocators are used as optimizations for speed. 
Allocations by the Operating system are slow. So your own memory manager grabs a large bucket of memory, and then makes the allocations for you from that memory bucket without going through the OS. This technique is more frequently used in games/consoles/embeded systems.

http://www.memorymanagement.org/articles/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-memorymanager/au-memorymanager-pdf.pdf

Answer (score 1):

malloc() is a library function in libc (or glibc) that makes a system call sbrk() when it needs to actually allocate more memory to the process.  Together, malloc() and free() manage a list of memory blocks that are used when malloc(), calloc() etc. are called.

You can use a custom allocator when malloc()'s behavior isn't desired or you want to do additional work on top of malloc/free.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't call `sbrk()` on Windows. ;) That's just an implementation detail in your OS, nothing to do with `malloc` itself.